# Determine when a script called from another script is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script, let's call it Script A. When Script A loads, it injects another script into the head of the document, Script B. Script B is where most of the important code lives.

When Script A is added to the host document it looks something like this:

```
<script async src="http//script-a.js" onload="doSomething();"></script>
```

In the `doSomething` function, I would like to trigger something from Script B. Unfortunately, it hasn't loaded yet, so an error occurs.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this that keeps the document in which Script A is embedded as simple as possible. How can I do this?

Comment: Find the injected script tag and listen to the onload event before doing what you need to do.

Comment: This feels like a weird implementation. Can't you manually add `script-b.js` before `script-a.js`? Why do you need `script-a.js` to do that?

Comment: @Fahmi Good question - the whole point of Script A is to load either a modern or legacy bundle (Script B) depending on the user's browser. In this way it can reduce the total bundle size.

Comment: Just use script tags without `async` and the `onload="doSomething();"`. `let useOnOtherScripts = "you can since it's scope is above load"; addEventListener('load', ()=> /* all scripts are already loaded so that variable up there is available to all scripts onload */ });`

Comment: @StackSlave A graceful solution, but a drawback is that you can't use `async` anymore. I don't want my scripts to be blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this and replace the url in the script for your "Script B."

```js
document.getElementById("demo").src = "https://my-random-script.glitch.me/script.js" // put your "Script B" here
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h2>Try to find a Hi! Alert Box</h2>
<script id="demo"></script>
```

The one where it calls something from external scripts

```js
document.getElementById("demo").src = "https://my-random-script.glitch.me/scriptb.js"
var b = "Hi!"
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = b;

alert("Hi")
function AlertAgain() {
alert("hi") // you can't use this, because the other site is blocking all scripts once all of the alerts are over! (you also can look at the site's js)
}
```

```html
<h1 id="text">Of course, load your scripts!</h1>
<script id="demo"></script>
<button onclick="AlertAgain()">Click to say hi again</button>
```

Demo without script that removes all scripts

```js
  var b = "Hi!"
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = b;

  alert("Hi")
  function AlertAgain() {
  alert("hi")
  }
```

```html
   <h1 id="text">Of course, load your scripts!</h1>
   <script id="demo"></script>
   <button onclick="AlertAgain()">Click to say hi again</button>
```

You can also have two different scripts on your HTML page.

Comment: Remember that there is also many more ways to add a script. (you could use something like a npm package)